# var not receiving correct value inside a function - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function called **getQuotes()**, and a **console.log()** at the end of it that shows the correct value of **currentQuote**.

```
function getQuote() {
      $.ajax({
            headers: {
              "X-Mashape-Key": "xxx",
              Accept: "application/json",
              "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            },
            url: 'https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/?cat=movies',
            success: function(response) {
                  var r = JSON.parse(response);      
                  currentQuote = r.quote;
                  currentAuthor = r.author; 
                  console.log(currentQuote);             
            }
      });
};
```

The point is: when I call **getFunction()** (like code below), then show a **console.log** of my variable **currentQuote**, it is not receiving the correct value, it still an empty string as declarated. What am I doing wrong ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var currentQuote='';
    var currentAuthor='';             
    getQuote();  
    console.log(currentQuote);        
});
```

Comment: since it is an AJAX-request it is likely that the request takes a little time. so maybe wait a few seconds before trying to `console.log(currentQuote)`

Comment: Quoting in this case doesn't matter for JS properties, and you'd actually have to write `"Accept":` instead to make it valid.

Comment: `$.ajax` is async. You code isn't. That's the story.

Comment: In addition to the above comments on synchronicity, have you debugged to check the response for the values? Also you should do something like Ted Hopp's answer below to ensure the response was received before trying to log the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Because `getQuote()` uses an Ajax call, when you call `getQuote()`, the operation proceeds asynchronously. That means that when `getQuote()` returns, the results are not yet available. You can fix this by supplying a call-back function as an argument to `getQuote()` and calling that function from the `success` function:

```
function getQuote(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
          "X-Mashape-Key": "xxx",
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        url: 'https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/?cat=movies',
        success: function(response) {
              var r = JSON.parse(response);      
              callback(r.quote, r.author); // Report success to the caller
        }
    });
};
```

Then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    getQuote(function(currentQuote, currentAuthor) { 
        console.log(currentQuote);
    });
});
```

This also eliminates the need for global `currentQuote` and `currentAuthor` variables. (Although you could always assign those in the callback, if the values are needed elsewhere.)

**Alternatives**

You can return a `Promise` from `getQuote` and modify the Ajax call to call the promise's `resolve` method. This is described in the accepted answer in the thread to which this is a duplicate.

Because you are using jQuery, another alternative to passing a call-back function is to return the `ajax` object itself, which has a convenient `done(result)` property:

```
function getQuote() {
    return $ajax({
        headers: {
          "X-Mashape-Key": "xxx",
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        url: 'https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/?cat=movies',
    });
}
```

And then use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    getQuote().done(function(result) {
        if (result) {
            var r = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(r.quote);
        }
    });
}};
```

This is also described in the duplicate thread. See [the docs for `$ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You have two separate issues.

First, remove the final `console.log` from your document-ready callback, and allow the success callback on your AJAX request to do the logging for you.

Second, you have two sets of `currentQuote` and `currentAuthor` variables: a set of global ones and a set that is locally-scoped to your document-ready callback. You should explicitly define each variable as a global property, like so, to prevent collisions:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    window.currentQuote = ''
    window.currentAuthor = ''             
    getQuote()        
});

function getQuote(cb) {
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            "X-Mashape-Key": "xxx",
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        url: 'https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/?cat=movies',
        success: function (response) {
              var r = JSON.parse(response)     
              window.currentQuote = r.quote
              window.currentAuthor = r.author 
              console.log(currentQuote)     
        }
    })
}
```

---

If you want to do more than just log the quotes and authors, there are a few ways to make your life a little easier: callbacks and Promises.

A callback is a function that is passed as a parameter to another (asynchronous) function and is called with some "return" value (like your quote and author) when the async process has completed. Here, I'm using `resolve` as the callback function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {            
    getQuote(function (quote, author) {
        // callback -- do stuff with `quote` and `author`
        console.log(quote, author)
    })
})

function getQuote(resolve) {
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            "X-Mashape-Key": "xxx",
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        url: 'https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/?cat=movies',
        success: function (response) {
              var result = JSON.parse(response)     
              resolve(r.quote, r.author)   
        }
    })
}
```

Promises are a more modern way to handle async code, but they are also less widely supported by default (This can be remedied with a polyfill). Promises are outside of the scope of this answer, but if you want more information then I would suggest checking out [the Promise page on the Mozilla Development Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: I'd suggest passing a callback as an argument that will run on success.

Comment: Of course, that's a possibility; you could also use Promises. I'll add a little blurb about callbacks in there if that would help.